# How do I count the number of times a method is used?

Tags: c#

[image][image]I have 2 dice that generate a number between 1 and 6. I want to display their values as follows:
"The value of dice 1 is: (Generated number)"
"The value of dice 2 is: (Generated number)"

My counter doesn't seem to work because my output is as following:
"The value of dice 1 is: (Generated number)"
"The value of dice 1 is: (Generated number)"

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program DungeonDiceMasters = new Program();
        DungeonDiceMasters.Start();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Dice d1, d2;
        d1 = new Dice();
        d2 = new Dice();

        d1.Throw();
        d2.Throw();

        d1.ShowValue();
        d2.ShowValue();

        Console.Write("\n");

        Console.ReadKey();
        Start();
    }


class Dice
{
    static Random NumberOneToSix = new Random();
    public int value;
    public int counter = 0;

    public void Throw()
    {
        value = NumberOneToSix.Next(1, 7);
    }

    public void ShowValue()
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        Console.WriteLine("The value of dice " + counter + " is: " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Each die has been rolled once.  Your counter is working.

Comment: If you want to share a variable between instances declare it as static

Comment: If it was, I wouldn't be posting this. 
The console outputs "The value of dice 1 is: (Random)" twice. Instead of doing "The value of dice 2 is: (Random)"

Comment: @LeroydeSmet Yes, because you have two dice, and each has been rolled once.  Roll one of them a second time.

Comment: I have and it continues to be 1. Look at the image I've provided.

Comment: Alpha was right, I had to add static to it, that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I get it now I think. Thank you Amy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a static field for the counter as follows:

```
public static int counter = 0;
```

but after each throw value is changed so it is a throw counter not the number of dice.
 output:

```
  The value of dice 1 is: 3
  The value of dice 2 is: 4
```

so you can use properties to save track of the dice count and the thrown number for each :

```
class Dice
{
    static Random NumberOneToSix = new Random();
    public int value;
    public static int diceCounter = 0;
    public  int diceNumber =0;
    public  int throwCounter = 0;
    //set id of dice in constructor method
    public  Dice(){
            diceCounter=diceCounter+1;
            diceNumber=diceCounter;
    }
    public void Throw()
    {
        value = NumberOneToSix.Next(1, 7);
        throwCounter=throwCounter+1;
    }

    public void ShowValue()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("The value of dice " + diceNumber +" in throw #"+throwCounter+ " is: " + value);
    }
}
```

and the output is :

```
The value of dice 1 in throw #1 is: 6
The value of dice 2 in throw #1 is: 3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Wasn't really familiar with constructors. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of the `Dice` class has a `counter` field, since the field is not static. They both have the value 1 as the `ShowValue` method has been called once for each dice instance.

You might want to add the dice numbering concept as a constructor parameter and manage the counting in your `Start` method instead.

Comment: Right, could you please give me a hint as to how to do the counting in the Start method? Or more specifically, how would I refer to the counter in my class? I'm extremely new to this so these terms are very hard for me to understand.

Comment: Create a constructor for `Dice` which accepts an integer parameter that is injected via the `Start` method when the die are being instantiated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Comment: Alright so I've created the constructor       
 public Dice(int i)
        {
        }
and I've instantiated d1 as Dice(1) and d2 as Dice(2)
but how do I now refer to it? And what do I put in the constructor? Sorry if I'm being stupid right now but like I said I'm very new to this and I want to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the number of die outside of the `Dice` instances because each instance will have their own local copy of `counter` which will start at 0 in both instances.

Add a constructor to the `Dice` class which accepts an `int` parameter to track the ID of which instance it is.

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start();
    }

    static void Start()
    {
        // Hold the Dice Counter outside of the scope of the instances
        int diceCounter = 0;
        Dice d1, d2;
        // Instantiate both dice, while incrementing the diceCounter and passing the value to the ctor
        d1 = new Dice(++diceCounter);
        d2 = new Dice(++diceCounter);

        d1.Throw();
        d2.Throw();

        d1.ShowValue();
        d2.ShowValue();

        Console.Write("\n");

        Console.ReadKey();
        Start();
    }
}

class Dice
{
    static Random NumberOneToSix = new Random();
    // int field which contains the ID/instance number for this instance.
    private readonly int identifier;
    public int value;

    // Constructor which accepts an int parameter
    public Dice(int identifier)
    {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public void Throw()
    {
        value = NumberOneToSix.Next(1, 7);
    }

    public void ShowValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The value of dice " + identifier + " is: " + value);
    }
}
```

You can read more about constructors [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

Here is also some information on the [this keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) as well as the [readonly keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The only thing confusing me is the line this.identifier = identifier;

What does this do and why do you 'this'? Also why does the identifier have to be read-only? Never seen that before either. Other then that I think I understand. In this case the dice count separately from one another right?

Comment: `this.identifier` access the `identifier` field on the current instance and assigns the value of `identifier` (the constructor parameter) to the local field. `readonly` means it can only be assigned to in the constructor at instantiation time and prevents it from being overwritten. I've included links in my answer to articles discussing each keyword.

Comment: Thank you so much dude. Maybe I won't fail my exam after all lmfao. Cheers lad

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest modifying your class just a bit. Reason being, that without some sort of external tracker like Jonas has suggested in his answer, you will not be able to keep track of dice rolls between method calls.

Try something like this:

```cs
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program DungeonDiceMasters = new Program();
        DungeonDiceMasters.Start();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        DiceRoller dr = new DiceRoller();

        dr.Throw();
        dr.ShowValue(true);
        dr.Throw();
        dr.ShowValue();

        Console.Write("\n");

        Console.ReadKey();
        Start();
    }


class DiceRoller
{
    static Random NumberOneToSix = new Random();
    public int value = 0;
    public int counter = 0;
    private bool diceThrown = false; //add throw tracker to avoid losing dice rolls

    public void Throw()
    {
        value = NumberOneToSix.Next(1, 7);
        diceThrown = true; //dice have been thrown
    }

    public void ShowValue(bool startOver = false) //optional parameter to reset dice counter
    {
        if(startOver) //if param set, reset counter
            counter = 0;
        counter = counter + 1;
        if(!diceThrown) // self-explanatory
            Throw(); //internal call to method to throw dice
        Console.WriteLine("The value of dice " + counter + " is: " + value);
        diceThrown = false; //reset dice throw tracker
    }
}
```

I added some comments to hopefully explain what's going on and why I made the edits I did. Hope this helps!